# AIRFLOW DAG need to be executed one by one upon success state

Tags: amazon-ec2, airflow

```
def build(self, **kwargs):
    # Check the status of the parent DAG run
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    print(ti)
    success = ti.get_dagrun().get_state() == 'success'
    failure = False

    if success:
        with self.get_dag() as dag:
            start = PythonOperator(
                task_id='START',
                python_callable=self.get_command,
                provide_context=True
            )

            CHILDDAG_TEST = TriggerDagRunOperator(
                task_id="EXECUTE-CHILDDAG",
                trigger_dag_id="CHILDDAG",
                conf={
                    "data": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='start') }}"
                },
                execution_date='{{ ds }}',
                reset_dag_run=True,
                wait_for_completion=True,
                poke_interval=60
            )

            start >> CHILDDAG_TEST
    else:
        failure
    return ti.get_dagrun().get_state()
```

am getting ti key error . If the code is works child dag is triggered without completing the main dag. Any one please help main_dag->success->child_dag.main_dag->failure->exit. anyone please help on this

please help on mentioned code